# Should we delete questions which need more details and the OP has abandoned us

Tags: discussion

Looking at this question: https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/1674/expresso-store-region-country-drop-down-menus

We need more information to answer this question. Therefore, it's extremely unlikely anyone will be able to come along later and provide an answer, and in its current form it's extremely unlikely it will be helpful to any future users. The OP seems to have abandoned it (and is unregistered which was probably half the problem).

Do you think we should simply delete questions like this if we don't get a response from the OP in a reasonable period of time (e.g. 1 month)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thinks it's fine to delete such questions after a reasonable amount of time.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect one of the main reasons for no-shows is that people expect the site to email them when someone responds... took me a while to realise this doesn't happen automatically. But to answer the question, I think deleting those Q's is fine. If they're important enough they'll crop up again at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed - they're not helping anyone by sitting there unanswered, especially in the case of very specific use-case questions.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is reasonable that if there has been a request for more detail and no response/no one has been able to effectively answer the question without more detail, it is completely reasonable, nay imperative, that the question be removed to keep the site slim and trim and really useful.  I would say a reasonable amount would be closer to a week than a month.